# Question shown as related, should be linked instead?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Question [What is "Microsoft C++ Visual Runtime Library: Runtime error!" and how can I capture it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215842) mentions [Disable Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938715) in both answers it has. Yet the question referenced is marked as related only, not linked.

Answer (score 1):

This was likely a bug in the linked crawl at some point - it's all linked up now.